# Why mixing write and printf seems to execute lines in the wrong order

Tags: c, gcc

I tried mixing write and printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
main()
{
    printf("ca");
    write(1, "lu", 2);
}
```

However, it **seems** to execute line 8 before line 7.

```
$ gcc bar.c 2>/dev/null && ./a.out
luca$
```

I am a beginner in C. I'd like to know what exactly happens here. Thanks!!!

Comment: selbie is right. `printf` is a 'buffered' write, meaning it stores the content in memory until it receives a newline character (´\n`) of you call `fflush(stdout)` (implicitely called upon closing the stream). It likely was conceived that way, because you expect console output to be 'line by line', instead of 'letter by letter'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is executing out of order.  It's just printing out of order.

When you invoke this:

```
write(1, "lu", 2);
```

You're telling the operating system to get those two charaters to the console (stdout) immediately. You are bypassing the C runtime for access to stdout.

But... `printf` as a member of the standard C library will buffer all the characters passed to it until a `\n` (end of line) char is seen.  There's some language and unix lawyers that can describe the relationship between `\n` and flusing to stdout more precisely.

Generally speaking, fewer I/O operations is a faster program, so buffering has its advantages - especially if stdout is getting redirected to disk.

So to summarize, printf doesn't actually get stuff to the screen until a `\n` char is sent to it or until the program is ready to exit.  This behavior may vary between platforms and console configurations.  `printf` will ultimately call `write(1,...)` but only after its got a reason to flush its contents.

But when you mix and match `printf` and another function that handles its own writing to stdout (console) without end of line chars, these types of unexpected results happen.

Comment: pchar isnt included. I tried renaming pchar to fjodsqjfdqs. I still had the same issue

Comment: I know that printf would handle the job. My question was why it executes in the wrong order

Comment: @luca112358 - Can you show me the implementation of pchar?  My psychic powers suggests it's not calling printf but perhaps bypassing the C runtime and doing something like `write(1, ...)` to flush its character buffer immediately.

Comment: By the way, nothing is executing in the wrong order. The correct way to describe the problem is that it's not flushing the output in the expected order.

Comment: Or if you just need a TLDR version, you can loosely assume that `printf` won't send anything to the console until `\n` is sent to it.

Comment: You changed the question after I wrote an answer. I still stand by the answer 100%.

Comment: it is because macros were confusing. The issue had nothing to do with macros but rather with the write function itself

Comment: write is unbuffered (obviously) whereas printf is. So it waits for the main func to end or \n char to be printed with printf or other non primitive functions from glibc. Thats why it "glitches". I got it thanks

Comment: I tried to write(1, "\n", 1) after printf but it didnt work since write is kind of primitive. i see. thx